# Determining RTK parameters for runoff analysis

Tags: hydrology, water-resources

I am examining a watershed and determining runoff using the RTK method. I basically use a 'guess and check the hydrograph' method right now. [I've seen calibrators](http://www.innovyze.com/products/infoswmm/calibrator.aspx) that use a mutation and convergence criteria using root mean square but I've had limited success using them. How can I perform this analysis more efficiently than using my 'guess and check' method?

Answer (score 1):

If your watershed is in the U.S., you might find TR-55 useful. "Technical Release 55 (TR-55) presents simplified procedures to calculate storm runoff volume, peak rate of discharge, hydrographs, and storage volumes required for floodwater reservoirs. These procedures are applicable in small watersheds, especially urbanizing watersheds, in the United States."  It can even be run on a calculator.

Comment: Technical Release 55 (TR-55) is published by the US Dept. of Argriture (USDA) which is available for download here. https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detailfull/national/water/?&cid=stelprdb1042925#:~:text=Technical%20Release%2055%20%28TR-55%29%20presents%20simplified%20procedures%20to,watersheds%2C%20especially%20urbanizing%20watersheds%2C%20in%20the%20United%20States.